# How can I modify and image inside a DIV by passing the cursor over the DIV

Tags: javascript, html

I'm starting out at coding and I'm stuck in a code that I'm working on. 
First I pass the mouse inside my DIV container called "Article" and everything inside change its opacity. I want just the image that is inside's opacity changed, so everywhere inside the DIV the opacity of the image should be 1. Once the mouse is out the opacity of the image should become 0.75. I tried multiple codes but the opacity changed for every element inside the DIV. Hope you could help me.

I tried to change document . getElementsByTagName ('article') [i] by document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i] but it just changed the image opacity when mouse is over the image. 
I tried document.getElementsByTagName('article')[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[i] same as before.
I tried to change this.style by img.style nothing happened...

```
for (var i = 0; i<document.querySelectorAll('article').length;i++)
document.getElementsByTagName('article')[i].onmouseover=function(){
this.style.opacity = 1;
}
for (var i = 0; i<document.querySelectorAll('article').length;i++)
document.getElementsByTagName('article')[i].onmouseleave=function(){
this.style.opacity = 0.75;
}
```

Hope that when I pass over an article the image opacity changes.
Thanks, you all an have a great year!

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't change the opacity using CSS?

Comment: In fact I want to make this work no because I can't change the opacity by passig by css but is cause I want my website to by like this. Thanks

Comment: a pure css solution using `:hover` would be a much better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Guys in fact at the end I change to css and it works perfectly sorry for being such a noobie and say that this doesn't work. I named my Article (DIV) "Dad" and my image "child".

OMG it was to simple and I complicate my life by a lot.
This is my final code:

```
.Dad:hover .Child {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using querySelectorAll('article img') instead of getElementsByTagName. This will only affect img inside article.

Comment: sorry it just modify when mouse is over images

Comment: I want that when mouse is over articles images inside articles are modified

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you asking for, but check this:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>this is container</h3>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?123" alt="">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?14" alt="">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?15" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    background: #d87300;
}

.half-transparent{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

JS

```
const images = [...document.querySelectorAll('.container img')]
const container = document.querySelector('.container')

container.addEventListener('mouseenter', ()=>{
    images.forEach(element => {
        element.classList.add('half-transparent')
    })
})

container.addEventListener('mouseleave', ()=>{
    images.forEach(element => {
        element.classList.remove('half-transparent')
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you it finally works!! but i modify a little bit

Comment: ^ (not sure) if you use pure CSS, everything in container will have opacity: text, images, container and each item inside

Comment: kaziutus sorry but it actually work better in fact now my mouse pass over the container an just image change. But it happen with all containers and I just want it to happen in the container my mouse is over.

Comment: Than if I pass my move over the second container it will no have any effect on images